# Expect script does not exit after completion

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, interpreter, expect

I have the following situation.

My main **expect** script looks something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set timeout 900
spawn main_ksh_script.ksh [lindex $argv 0]
expect {
        "Press ENTER to Continue" {
            send_user "Message1\n"
            send "\r"
            exp_continue}
        "Press any key to continue" {
            send "\r"
            exp_continue}
         eof {
            send "\003\177\015"
            send_user "EOF reached\n"
            exit 0}
         timeout {
            send_user "Job timed out\n"
            send "\003\177\015"
            exit 100}
}
interact {
\015 {send "\015"}
\003 {send "\003\177\015"}
"\033\[3~" {send "\177"}
}
```

My main **korn** shell script (main_ksh_script.ksh) is a really huge script that does many things to the desired environmet. One of those things is running deamons and some remote jobs. Here's very short example...

```
while true; do
    clear
    echo "\n\tDo You Want to deploy xxx!!!  ([Yes]/No) \c"
    read yn1 ;
    case ${yn1} in
    [Yy]*|$enter)
        clear
        echo "SomeJobName1" on Environment (${envNum})\n"
        secondScript.expect environment$envNum@host "Some command(s)"
        echo "End of SomeJobName1" on Environment (${envNum})\n"

        echo "SomeJobName2" on Environment (${envNum})\n"
        secondScript.expect environment$envNum@host "Some command(s)"
        echo "End of SomeJobName2" on Environment (${envNum})\n"

        #And so on...
        break ;;
    [Nn]*) break ;;
    *) echo "\n\tPlease choose Yes or No\c"; pau ;;
    esac
    pau
done
```

secondScript.expect looks something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set timeout 300
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no [lindex $argv 0] -n [lindex $argv 1]
expect {
        "Operational Job ended successfully" {
                send "\003\177\015"
                exp_continue}
        "Operational Job ended with failure" {
                send "\003\177\015"
                exp_continue}
        "Press ENTER to Continue" {
                send "\r"
                exp_continue}
        "Press any key to continue" {
                send "\r"
                exp_continue}
        "Password:" {
                send "mypassword\r"
                exp_continue}
        eof {
                send "\003\177\015"
                send_user "EOF reached\n"
                exit 0}
        timeout {
                send "\003\177\015"
                exit 100}
}
interact
```

Problem is, that when the main_ksh_script.ksh finishes, the first expect script (the one that invoked it by spawning a process) does not exit. I have to opet new terminal, and kill it by "kill -9". Can't even send Ctrl+c.

Edit...
If I remove "interact" from both expect scripts, I got no results. This is how the tail of the main script looks like.

```
expect: does " \c\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Press ENTER to Continue"? no
"Press any key to continue"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \c\r\n\r\n"
```

It still won't terminate by itself, and I still can not kill it by any other way, expect by kill command from another terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first expect script to end, what is the `interact` command doing at the end?
You need your `interact` command to detect eof.

```
interact {
  ...
  -o
  eof {puts "spawned process completed"; exit}
}
```

The `-o` indicates that the following rules ("eof") are to be detected from the spawned process, not from the user.

Comment: Thank you glenn for your help. I'm not sure that I fully understood you. So, I should remove everything (these three lines) from interact command in the main/first expect script, and replace it with -o and eof??? Should I also remove interact from the second expect script?

Comment: I guess I don't understand you: how is the 2nd script related to the ksh script? Is the 2nd script truly meant to be used interactively?

Comment: I edited the original post, I hope this will be less confusing. In a nutshell, 2nd script is used in the main korn script as a command on many places. Please review the question again, I think now it will be clear what's their relation.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of ending your expect scripts with "interact"? If not, try removing those trailing interact commands.

Comment: I tried removing them, but got no results. I edited the original question and added the tail of the main expect script to it. Please review it, maybe it will be helpful. I'm sorry for the late answer, but I can't run this script whenever I want...